# Objects real mass?

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, mass, mass-energy

If an object gains [relativistic mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_in_special_relativity) when moving and we are consistently moving with our planet, solar system and galaxy, does this speed increase the relativistic mass for example of the earth? And if the galaxy wouldn’t move, would it mass be lesser than it is?

Comment: Mass doesn't increase with speed. This is an outdated concept.

Comment: The link you provided states _clearly_ in at least two places that relativistic mass is outdated and not useful, did you read it?